# ( problem with authentication) React native my first time trying to authenticate

Tags: javascript, react-native, validation, authentication

error appears on line -> const [data, setData] = React.useState({

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    TextInput,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import {auth} from './firebase'
import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';




const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {




    const [data, setData] = React.useState({   //<- error that is returned to me
      
        Email: '',
        username: '',
        password: '',
        confirm_password: '',
        check_textInputChange: false,
        secureTextEntry: true,
        confirm_secureTextEntry: true,
       
    });
    
    const register = async () => {
        try{
          //  <-here is my attempt to authenticate 

        const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            data)  ;
        console.log(user)
        }catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        
        }
        
        
        };
//nome
    const textInputChange = (val) => {
        if( val.length !== 0 ) {
            setData({
                ...data,
                username: val,
                check_textInputChange: true
            });
```

//my validation attempt that I also have error like for example, how does it do for when I click //the button check if the fields are not empty among other things I put

```
        } else {
            setData({
                ...data,
                username: val,
                check_textInputChange: false
            });
        }
    }
// email
    const textInputChangert = (val) => {
        if( val.length !== 0 ) {
            setData({
                ...data,
                Email: val,
                check_textInputChangert: true
            });
        } else {
            setData({
                ...data,
                Email: val,
                check_textInputChangert: false
            });
        }
    }
  

    const handlePasswordChange = (val) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            password: val
        });
    }

    const handleConfirmPasswordChange = (val) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            confirm_password: val
        });
    }

    const updateSecureTextEntry = () => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry
        });
    }

    const updateConfirmSecureTextEntry = () => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            confirm_secureTextEntry: !data.confirm_secureTextEntry
        });
    }

   



    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor='#009387' barStyle="light-content"/>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.text_header}>Cadastro</Text>
        </View>
        <Animatable.View 
            animation="fadeInUpBig"
            style={styles.footer}
        >
           
            <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Nome</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <FontAwesome 
                    name="user-o"
                    color="#05375a"
                    size={20}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Nome"
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(val) => textInputChange(val)}
                    onChange={(event) => {

                       

                    }}
                />
                {data.check_textInputChange ? 
                <Animatable.View
                    animation="bounceIn"
                >
                    <Feather 
                        name="check-circle"
                        color="green"
                        size={20}
                    />

                        

                    
                </Animatable.View>






                : null}
            </View>


            <ScrollView>
            <Text style={[styles.text_footer, {
                marginTop: 35 }]}>Email</Text>

            <View style={styles.action}>
                <FontAwesome 
                    name="user-o"
                    color="#05375a"
                    size={20}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Exemplo@email.com"
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(val) => textInputChangert(val)}
                    onChange={(event) => {

                        

                    }}
                />
                {data.check_textInputChangert ? 
                <Animatable.View
                    animation="bounceIn"
                >
                    <Feather 
                        name="check-circle"
                        color="green"
                        size={20}
                    />

                        

                    
                </Animatable.View>

                : null}

            </View>


            <Text style={[styles.text_footer, {
                marginTop: 35
            }]}>Senha</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <Feather 
                    name="lock"
                    color="#05375a"
                    size={20}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="senha"
                    secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(val) => handlePasswordChange(val)}

                    onChange={(event) => {

                        

                    }}

                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={updateSecureTextEntry}
                >
                    {data.secureTextEntry ? 
                    <Feather 
                        name="eye-off"
                        color="grey"
                        size={20}
                    />
                    :
                    <Feather 
                        name="eye"
                        color="grey"
                        size={20}
                    />
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <Text style={[styles.text_footer, {
                marginTop: 35
            }]}>Confirma Senha</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <Feather 
                    name="lock"
                    color="#05375a"
                    size={20}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Confirma Senha"
                    secureTextEntry={data.confirm_secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(val) => handleConfirmPasswordChange(val)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={updateConfirmSecureTextEntry}
                >
                    {data.secureTextEntry ? 
                    <Feather 
                        name="eye-off"
                        color="grey"
                        size={20}
                    />
                    :
                    <Feather 
                        name="eye"
                        color="grey"
                        size={20}
                    />
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
         
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.signIn}
                    onPress={() => navigation.SignInScreen()}
                >
              
                    <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                        color:'#fff'
                    }]}>Logar</Text>
            
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={SignInScreen}
                    onClick={register}
                    style={[styles.signIn, {
                        backgroundColor:'#5961EE',
                        marginTop: 15,
                        borderColor:'#5961EE',
                        borderWidth:2,
                    }]}
                >
                    <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                        color: '#FFF'
                    }]}>Cadastrar</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </Animatable.View>
      </View>
    );
};

export default SignInScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1, 
      backgroundColor: '#0F17A7'
    },
    header: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingBottom: 50
    },
    footer: {
        flex: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 3 : 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 30
    },
    text_header: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30
    },
    text_footer: {
        color: '#05375a',
        fontSize: 18
    },
    action: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',
        paddingBottom: 5
    },
    textInput: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : -12,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        color: '#05375a',
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 50
    },
    signIn: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10
    },
    textSign: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    textPrivate: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        marginTop: 20
    },
    color_textPrivate: {
        color: 'grey'
    }
  });
```

this error appeared when I'm trying to authenticate it's the first time I've done this and I'm not sure how I can do it, mainly adapted to my code.